# AMP pages for API base system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accelerated-mobile-page, google-amp

We are trying to move our pages to `Google AMP` for better mobile and SEO experience. Problem is our system is API base totally. We are using nodejs along with react as of now.

Since in AMP you cannot use javascript to make ajax API calls, is there any way to implement to AMP through API's? Searched on the web but not able to find a optimal solution

Comment: you should check Isomorphic/Universal App, that can help.

Answer (score 2):

You will need an intermediary http server which makes those API calls and generates static HTML which is served to clients.

Comment: This will be too hard maintainability-wise. Right?

Comment: Not so much if you use react and universal rendering. You can use your react components for generating AMP pages - it is just that they will not be hydrated client side.

Answer (score 0):

As React and Angular both supports server side rendering. You can use [ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(element)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) to generate static html on server while using benefit of react component structure.

- You can use node server to make API call and pass that data to your React component which will generate AMP html later using renderToStaticMarkup.
- You can also use [redux-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-connect), npm library which wait for API to resolve on server before rendering react component.